# Redux form initialize only once though form names are different all the times

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am using redux form **5.3.2**

My app needs user to submit N forms, ( value of N is decided at run time )

I receive only 1 form's fields, initial values & form Id from API.

As user submit 1st form, I send data to server and I get fields, initial values anf form id for second form.

I have a common form component to which I pass fields, initiaval values and form name all the times.

Code snippet is as below

In side parent component

```
<CommonForm
  fields={myFields}
  initialValues={fieldsInitialValues}
  form={`form-${formId.toString()}`}
  temp={fieldsInitialValues}
  />
```

Inside form component

```
class CommonForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    values: PropTypes.object,
    temp: PropTypes.object
  }
  // other code and methods

  render(){
    // form rendering....
  }
} // end of class

export default reduxForm({
  // form: this value I am sending from parent component
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  validate: formValidator,
  overwriteOnInitialValuesChange: true
})(CommonForm);
```

I read about overwriteOnInitialValuesChange from http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/api/reduxForm?_k=f2zdrg

In redux store all forms are stored separetly under forms key

like form-1, form-2 etc

Problem is initial values are assigned only first time, next time I am getting undefined.

I dumped temp in side CommonForm, I am getting expected values like { field1: some value, field2: } some value

Where are things are going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "only first time"? They aren't updated when you change them and pass as a prop to `CommonForm` or only one form `form-1` gets the `initialValues`?

Comment: @DmitriyNevzorov form-1 gets initialValues but form-2 does not get - all fields values are showing as undefined.

Comment: How do you use `CommonForm` in the loop?

Comment: any solution still?